# Reducer/Action refactor

Tags: javascript, redux, refactoring, reduce

I have the following reducer:

```
...
case PAGE_CHANGED: {
  return {
    ...state,
    property: {
      ...state.property,
      currentPage: action.payload.page
    }
  }
}
...
```

my initialState looks like this:

```
export const initialState: RepairsState = {
  property: {...s},
  commercial: {...s}
}
```

where s is:

```
const s = {
  data: [],
  isFetching: false,
  ...paginationInitialState
}
```

and the paginationInitialState is like so:

```
const paginationInitialState: PaginationState = {
  currentPage: 0,
  orderBy: '',
  resultsPerPage: 10,
  searchTerm: '',
  sortableFields: [],
  totalCount: 0
}
```

commercial and property have the same state structure but will have different content.

When I update the PAGE_CHANGED reducer I use the following action:

```
export const pageChanged = (page: number): ThunkAction<void, AppState, null, Action<string>> => (
  dispatch: Dispatch,
  getState: () => AppState
) => {
  const searchTerm = getLatestSearchTerm(getState())
  dispatch({
    type: PAGE_CHANGED,
    payload: { page },
  })

  dispatch(searchForRepairs(searchTerm) as any)
}
```

for the commercial property I don't want recreate another action to update the commercial PAGE_CHANGED reducer. I want to avoid duplicating action logic.

I thought about passing an additional parameter when the action is called in the UI like so:

```
pageChanged(2, 'commercial')
```

so that I can have an if statement inside the action, is there a more clean solution than this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able dispatch `pageChanged(2, 'commercial')`

Then this might work:

```
export const commercialPageChanged = (page: number) => {
  return pageChanged(page, 'commercial');
}

export const propertyPageChanged = (page: number) => {
  return pageChanged(page, 'property');
}
```

That way your components are not dependent on knowing what value to pass as the second argument to `pageChanged`.